# I need to return string from async await function to variable

Tags: javascript, async-await

```javascript
async function generateNextNrOf() {
    const companyOf = await Company.find().limit(1).sort({ $natural: -1 });
    const now = new Date();
    const month = now.getUTCMonth() + 1;
    const year = now.getUTCFullYear();
    let poprzedniNr = companyOf[0].nrOf;
    let checkingTab = [];
    checkingTab = poprzedniNr.split('/');

    if (month === parseFloat(checkingTab[0])) {
        let newNumber = `${month}/${year}/Of/${parseFloat(checkingTab[3]) + 1}`;
        console.log(newNumber);
        return newNumber;
    } else {
        let newNumber = `${month}/${year}/Of/1`;
        console.log(newNumber);
        return newNumber;
    }
}
```

I checking from MongoDB last record, I am looking for a variable named "nrOf" (`4/2022/Of/1`).
I try generate next number like `4/2022/Of/2` and so on and so forth.
If I try run `generateNextNrOf();` I only get the Promise, but i need this result "pass" to variable, like `const exampleVariable = '4/2022/Of/2';`
I know async/await always return a Promise, but probably is the solution for my case.

Comment: You need an await before an async function for it to return the value inside the promise. So something like `const exampleVriable = await generateNextNrOf()`

Comment: I write `const exampleVriable = await generateNextNrOf();
console.log(exampleVriable);` and i get: "const exampleVriable = await generateNextNrOf();
                       ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function"

Comment: I think you put this code 
const exampleVriable = await generateNextNrOf();
in non async function.
example : 
async main(){
const exampleVriable = await generateNextNrOf();
}

Answer (score 0):

```
async function generateNextNrOf() {
    const companyOf = await Company.find().limit(1).sort({ $natural: -1 
    });
    const now = new Date();
    const month = now.getUTCMonth() + 1;
    const year = now.getUTCFullYear();
    let poprzedniNr = companyOf[0].nrOf;
    let checkingTab = [];
    checkingTab = poprzedniNr.split('/');

    if (month === parseFloat(checkingTab[0])) {
        let newNumber = 
      `${month}/${year}/Of/${parseFloat(checkingTab[3]) + 1}`;
        console.log(newNumber);
        return newNumber;
    } else {
        let newNumber = `${month}/${year}/Of/1`;
        console.log(newNumber);
        return newNumber;
    }
}
```

I think you are calling this function from non-async function.Like this--

```
function main(){
   const exampleVriable = await generateNextNrOf(); 
   console.log(exampleVriable);
}
```

So the problem is main is not an async function ,thus you cannot use await in main.
To solve this problem you must use async keyword before main.Here is the solution.

```
async function main(){
   const exampleVriable = await generateNextNrOf(); 
   console.log(exampleVriable);
}
```